# Rails 3 : Write a view helper for popovers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, view-helpers

I am new to rails and in my current project I'm using [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap) from Twitter.
Bootstrap's popover are beautiful and I plan to use them extensively so I want to write a view helper for popover.

Here is the standart html code for a popover :

```
<div id="modal-from-dom" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    /* popover header's code here */
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    /* popover body's code here */
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    /* popover footer's code here */
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
/* button to show the popover */
```

Here is my helper function :

```
def render_popup(before,id ,button ,header, body, footer, after)
result = before.html_safe
result += '<div id="'.html_safe
result += id.html_safe
result += '" class="modal hide fade">'.html_safe
result += '<div class="modal-header">'.html_safe
result += '<a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>'.html_safe
result += header.html_safe
result += '</div>'.html_safe
result += '<div class="modal-body">'.html_safe
result += body.html_safe
result += '</div>'.html_safe
result += '<div class="modal-footer">'.html_safe
result += footer.html_safe
result += '</div>'.html_safe
result += '</div>'.html_safe
result += after.html_safe
result += '<button data-controls-modal="'.html_safe
result += id.html_safe
result += '" data-backdrop="true" data-keyboard="true" class="btn primary">'.html_safe
result += button.html_safe
result += '</button>'.html_safe
return result.html_safe
end
```

I'm aware that this function is ugly but I haven't find a better way to write it :/
Maybe with some blocks ?

And finally the code in my view to call this helper

```
<% before = form_tag url_for(:controller => "refunds" , :action => "create"), :method => :post %>
<% header = '<h3>Remboursement</h3>'%>
<% body = capture do %>
     <p>
         <p style="margin-top:15px"><b>Montant : (€)</b></p>
         <%= text_field_tag :amount, nil, :placeholder => "ex : 123.45", :class => "span3" %>
         <p style="margin-top:15px"><b>Destination</b></p>
         <%= select_tag :user_id, options_for_select(@users_select), :class => "span3" %>
         <p><br /></p>
         <%= hidden_field_tag :current_user_id, @currentUser.id %>
      </p>
<% end %>
<% footer = submit_tag "Rembourser", :class => "btn primary", :id =>"Rembourser" %>
<% after = "</form>" %>

<div style="margin-top:30px;text-align:center">
  <%= render_popup (before,'refund', '+ Rembourser', header, body, footer, after)%>
</div>
```

As you can see I have a form splited across the popover. Form's field are in the body and the submit button is in the footer. The popover is displayed correctly but the submit button doesn't work (it works without the helper).

How I can write properly the helper function and handle the spited form problem ?

---

### Update 1

Based on nathanvda answer's and clyfe comment's I have edited my helper and created a partial.
Here is the code of the partial :

```
<%= before %>
<div id="<%= popover_id %>" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    <%= header%>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= body %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <%= footer %>
  </div>
</div>
<%= after %>
<button data-controls-modal="<%= popover_id %>" data-backdrop="true" data-keyboard="true"   class="btn primary">
    <%= button %>
</button>
```

and the helper method :

```
def render_popup(before,id ,button ,header, body, footer, after)
render :partial => 'shared/popover', 
       :locals => { :popover_id => id, 
                    :header => header.html_safe,
                    :body => body, 
                    :footer => footer.html_safe,
                    :button => button,
                    :before => before, 
                    :after => after.html_safe}
end
```

The view's code doesn't change.
It's cleaner and the form is displayed correctly, but the submit button doesn't work better (nothing happend when I click on it). Anny suggestions ?

---

### Update 2

By comparing the generated html code with the helper and without it I have found the submit problem. The `form_tag` wasn't on the right place.
With this code in the view it works :

```
<% header = '<h3>Remboursement</h3>'%>
<% body = capture do %>
  <p>
    <%= form_tag url_for(:controller => "refunds" , :action => "create"), :method => :post %>
    <p style="margin-top:15px"><b>Montant : (€)</b></p>
    <%= text_field_tag :amount, nil, :placeholder => "ex : 123.45", :class => "span3" %>
    <p style="margin-top:15px"><b>Destination</b></p>
    <%= select_tag :user_id, options_for_select(@users_select), :class => "span3" %>
    <p><br /></p>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :current_user_id, @currentUser.id %>
  </p>
<% end %>
<% footer = submit_tag "Rembourser", :class => "btn primary", :id =>"Rembourser" %>
<% after = "</form>" %>

<div style="margin-top:30px;text-align:center">
  <%= render_popup (nil,'refund', '+ Rembourser', header, body, footer, after)%>
</div>
```

Now I have a working solution but it's not perfect. It would be very nice if I could drop `after = "</form>"` ?

Comment: Move the html from the helper to a a partial first, so my eyes stop bleeding. Clean the code more (refactor). Don't put p's in p's it's not valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a folder `app/views/shared`, in that folder add a partial called `_popover.html.erb` containing:

```
<%= before %>
<div id="<%= popover_id %>" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    <%= header%>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= body %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <%= footer %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
<%= after %>
<button data-controls-modal="<%= popover_id %>'" data-backdrop="true" data-keyboard="true" class="btn primary">
  <%= button %>
</button>
```

And in your helper you can then just write:

```
def render_popup(before,id ,button ,header, body, footer, after)
  render :partial => 'shared/popover', 
         :locals => {:popover_id => id, :header => header, :body => body, 
                     :footer => footer, :before => before, :after => after}
end
```

Hope this helps.